# how to remove special word from a string in function

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

Write a function fun(long string) with one string parameter that returns a string. The function should extract the words separated by a single space " ", exclude/drop empty words as well as words that are equal to "end" and "exit", convert the remaining words to upper case, join them with the joining token string ";" and return this newly joined string.
my code is......

def fun(long_string):
long_string = long_string.split(' ')

```
try:
    if 'exit' in long_string:
        long_string.remove('exit')
    elif 'end' in long_string:
        long_string.remove('end')
except ValueError:
                pass
```

.....................
but it does not remove the "End or exit" .can someone pls help me to get it out. Im beginner in  python and I stack here

Comment: Can you give an example of at least one of your input strings?

Comment: `except pass` is very unhelpful when you're trying to debug your code.

Comment: Input: "this is a long test exit string"
Output: "THIS;IS;A;LONG;TEST;STRING"
@NathanRoberts

Comment: Given your own sample input `above`, what do you expect?  First there is no such word `end` or `exit`?  and these words are not separated by `space`?  So can you at least try to give your `function definition` and expected output(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this and convert into the `function` as you wish - it's very straightforward.

Code did not fully test **yet** *(but works for your inputs)*, so please try different inputs and you can learn to "improve" it to meet your requirement.  Please ask if you have any questions.

```
inputs =  "this is a long test exit string"     

stop_words = ('end', 'exit')

outs = ''

for word in inputs.split():
    if word in stop_words:
        outs = inputs.replace(word, " ")

ans = ';'.join(w.upper() for w in outs.split())  # do the final conversion
```

#### Confirm it:

```
assert ans == "THIS;IS;A;LONG;TEST;STRING"    # silent means True
```

#### Edit:  add function:

```
def fun(long_string):
    #s = "this is a long test exit string" 

    stop_words = ('end', 'exit')
    outs  = ''

    for word in long_string.split():
        if word in stop_words:
            outs = long_string.replace(word, " ")
    
    ans = ';'.join(w.upper() for w in outs.split())
    return ans
        
text = "this is a long test exit string" 
print(fun(text))
```

Comment: is it possible to send u full code? because im still struggling

Comment: This is the `full` code.  Do you mean the `function`?  OR you still got stuck somewhere?

Comment: OK. I've added the `fun` function - check it out.

Comment: yep... it done... ur post